# calculate XOR of first 2 (binary-)values in numpy array triples

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy and have an np.array with inputs that are 3 bits each, looking like this:

```
[[0 1 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

The targets should be the XOR of the first two input bits (y = XOR(x0, x1)) in another numpy array.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.bitwise_xor()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html):

```
np.bitwise_xor(arr[:,0], arr[:, 1])
```

Demo:

```
In [112]: np.bitwise_xor(arr[:,0], arr[:, 1])
Out[112]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: thanks! i realize, that i also need futher basic Python syntax experience like array assignments.